# Getting a weird straight line in my graphs

Tags: gnuplot

Finding it really weird how I'm getting a straight line in the graphs which are produced with my gnuplot scripts. I followed an example and weirdly enough there example doesn't have this straight line in theirs.

[image: gnuplot graph]

This is the code for how I created this graph.

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
set terminal png
set term png size 1200, 800
set lmargin 8
set rmargin 4
set tmargin 3
set bmargin 3
set output "cpu.png"
set title "CPU usage"
set xlabel "time"
set ylabel "percent"
set xdata time
set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M:%S"
set xrange ["15:43:59":"15:48:56"]
plot "cpu.txt" using 1:3 title "user" with lines
```

It'd be great if someone who had a similar problem to mine could share their solution to this problem. Thanks.

Here's my 'cpu.txt' file which is used to produce the first graph - http://pastebin.com/46i3XTM7

Comment: You don't need to show three similar graphs, the first one is enough. But you must show your data file (`cpu.txt`), which is were the problem comes from.

Comment: @Christoph I added the cpu.txt file as a link, it's quite long so didn't want to paste all of it my question.

Comment: How does gnuplot handle that very last row, first column, where the time is `Average:`? I'm guessing it defaults it to 0, so you get a last line from the last point on the right all the way to the beginning. And your `range` option prevents you from seeing the line extending all the way back to 0.

Comment: @MOS182 Yes, it is long, but the last line in the data file is where the error comes from ;)

Comment: @Evert Yes, right guess :) Would you mind adding this as answer?

Comment: @Evert so the best way to stop it would be to remove the last line? Is there a way to remove the last line without having to specify the line number with sed?

Comment: You can use `plot '< head -n -1 cpu.txt' using 1:3` to remove the last line on-the-fly.

Comment: @Christoph: nah, I'll leave any answer to you, since you came up with the correct hint, and a convenient solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To illustrate the source of the problem, here are the relevant parts of the last two lines of `cpu.txt`:

```
15:48:56        all      0.46
Average:        all      0.41
```

The `Average` isn't a valid time, so the gnuplot parser returns `0`, which is far left in your plot and which produces the horizontal line.

To remove the last line on-the-fly, you can use the `head` command line tool:

```
plot "< head -n -1 cpu.txt" using 1:3 title "user" with lines
```